# for Yii framework, what CForm element types are available?

Tags: php, yii

When creating a CForm object, I can pass in the type of form element in the `options` array:

```
$form = new CForm(array(
    'elements' => array(
        'name' => array('type' => 'text'),
    )
));
```

I'm not sure what other types of elements are available and they aren't listed in [the CForm api docs.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm#elements-detail)

The [CFormElementCollection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormElementCollection) class doesn't list any types of elements either.

How do I find out all the types of form elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [CFormInputElement](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormInputElement) and [CFormButtonElement](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormButtonElement)

## Form Input Element Types

element types currently include:

- text
- hidden
- password
- textarea
- file
- radio
- checkbox
- listbox
- dropdownlist
- checkboxlist
- radiolist
- url
- email
- number
- range
- date

## Button Element Types

for the buttons you can also set the type, the current list is:

- htmlButton
- htmlReset
- htmlSubmit
- submit
- button
- image
- reset
- link